# Bundle Install can not find compatible version of "activesupport" for google-drive

Tags: railsapps

Hello all I am working on a demo application and have noticed that I get this error after inserting the gem google-drive gem into my Gemfile.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
google-drive (>= 0) ruby depends on
  middleman-core (>= 3.2.2) ruby depends on
    activesupport (~> 3.2.6) ruby

rails (= 4.1.1) ruby depends on
  activesupport (4.1.1)
```

To me it looks like the google-drive gem requires an earlier version of activesupport than what rails 4.1.1 requires. Any advice is welcomed.

Comment: Try running `bundle update`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Fork `google-drive` gem, update dependencies to any, and check if it works. ACtually, if you use [this](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem, i don't see any `middleman-core` dependencies. Alos try to use `master` branch:

```
gem 'google-drive', github: 'gimite/google-drive-ruby' # or other path, which you use
```

To change dependencies just edit `gemspec` file in your repo, after fork. And then change gem path (`gimite/google-drive-ruby`) to yours.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... That actually didn't fix it but while on the google drive github read me I noticed they were using google_drive and not google-drive as the gem name.